# Error message with code: “URL scheme in your app's manifest is not set up correctly.”

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-manifest

Hi again this time I am posting the code.Please someone verify and do let me know what is problem I am facing here. I am trying to install apk in mobile via eclipse but I keep on getting error "URL scheme in your app's manifest is not set up correctly. You should have a com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity with the scheme:" does anyone have an idea how to tackle this error. Thank you.

Manifest code:-`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.dropbox.android.sample"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

      <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity

          android:name=".DBRoulette"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
          android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivitywith"
          android:launchMode="singleTask"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
          <intent-filter>
            <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
            <data android:scheme="db-8bptwiadb9rgms2" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>

      </application>
    </manifest> 
`
```

Java code:-`

```
 package com.dropbox.android.sample;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
    import com.dropbox.client2.android.AndroidAuthSession;
    import com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity;
    import com.dropbox.client2.session.AccessTokenPair;
    import com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair;


    public class DBRoulette extends Activity {
        private static final String TAG = "DBRoulette";

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //                      Your app-specific settings.                      //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Replace this with your app key and secret assigned by Dropbox.
        // Note that this is a really insecure way to do this, and you shouldn't
        // ship code which contains your key & secret in such an obvious way.
        // Obfuscation is good.
        final static private String APP_KEY = "8bptwiadb9rgms2E";
        final static private String APP_SECRET = "i7bh698kx6qldk7";

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //                      End app-specific settings.                       //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // You don't need to change these, leave them alone.
        final static private String ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
        final static private String ACCESS_KEY_NAME = "ACCESS_KEY";
        final static private String ACCESS_SECRET_NAME = "ACCESS_SECRET";

        private static final boolean USE_OAUTH1 = false;

        DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mApi;

        private boolean mLoggedIn;

        // Android widgets
        private Button mSubmit;
        private LinearLayout mDisplay;
        private Button mPhoto;
        private Button mRoulette;

        private ImageView mImage;

        private final String PHOTO_DIR = "/Photos/";

        final static private int NEW_PICTURE = 1;
        private String mCameraFileName;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mCameraFileName = savedInstanceState.getString("mCameraFileName");
            }

            // We create a new AuthSession so that we can use the Dropbox API.
            AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
            mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

            // Basic Android widgets
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            checkAppKeySetup();

            mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.auth_button);

            mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // This logs you out if you're logged in, or vice versa
                    if (mLoggedIn) {
                        logOut();
                    } else {
                        // Start the remote authentication
                        if (USE_OAUTH1) {
                            mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(DBRoulette.this);
                        } else {
                            mApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(DBRoulette.this);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            mDisplay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.logged_in_display);

            // This is where a photo is displayed
            mImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);

            // This is the button to take a photo
            mPhoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.photo_button);

            mPhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    // Picture from camera
                    intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    // This is not the right way to do this, but for some reason, having
                    // it store it in
                    // MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI isn't working right.

                    Date date = new Date();
                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-kk-mm-ss");

                    String newPicFile = df.format(date) + ".jpg";
                    String outPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), newPicFile).getPath();
                    File outFile = new File(outPath);

                    mCameraFileName = outFile.toString();
                    Uri outuri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outuri);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Importing New Picture: " + mCameraFileName);
                    try {
                        startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_PICTURE);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        showToast("There doesn't seem to be a camera.");
                    }
                }
            });


            // This is the button to take a photo
            mRoulette = (Button)findViewById(R.id.roulette_button);

            mRoulette.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DownloadRandomPicture download = new DownloadRandomPicture(DBRoulette.this, mApi, PHOTO_DIR, mImage);
                    download.execute();
                }
            });

            // Display the proper UI state if logged in or not
            setLoggedIn(mApi.getSession().isLinked());

        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            outState.putString("mCameraFileName", mCameraFileName);
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            AndroidAuthSession session = mApi.getSession();

            // The next part must be inserted in the onResume() method of the
            // activity from which session.startAuthentication() was called, so
            // that Dropbox authentication completes properly.
            if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    // Mandatory call to complete the auth
                    session.finishAuthentication();

                    // Store it locally in our app for later use
                    storeAuth(session);
                    setLoggedIn(true);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    showToast("Couldn't authenticate with Dropbox:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Error authenticating", e);
                }
            }
        }

        // This is what gets called on finishing a media piece to import
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == NEW_PICTURE) {
                // return from file upload
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri uri = null;
                    if (data != null) {
                        uri = data.getData();
                    }
                    if (uri == null && mCameraFileName != null) {
                        uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFileName));
                    }
                    File file = new File(mCameraFileName);

                    if (uri != null) {
                        UploadPicture upload = new UploadPicture(this, mApi, PHOTO_DIR, file);
                        upload.execute();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Unknown Activity Result from mediaImport: "
                            + resultCode);
                }
            }
        }

        private void logOut() {
            // Remove credentials from the session
            mApi.getSession().unlink();

            // Clear our stored keys
            clearKeys();
            // Change UI state to display logged out version
            setLoggedIn(false);
        }

        /**
         * Convenience function to change UI state based on being logged in
         */
        private void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
            mLoggedIn = loggedIn;
            if (loggedIn) {
                mSubmit.setText("Unlink from Dropbox");
                mDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mSubmit.setText("Link with Dropbox");
                mDisplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mImage.setImageDrawable(null);
            }
        }

        private void checkAppKeySetup() {
            // Check to make sure that we have a valid app key
            if (APP_KEY.startsWith("CHANGE") ||
                    APP_SECRET.startsWith("CHANGE")) {
                showToast("You must apply for an app key and secret from developers.dropbox.com, and add them to the DBRoulette ap before trying it.");
                finish();
                return;
            }

            // Check if the app has set up its manifest properly.
            Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String scheme = "db-" + APP_KEY;
            String uri = scheme + "://" + AuthActivity.AUTH_VERSION + "/test";
            testIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            if (0 == pm.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, 0).size()) {
                showToast("URL scheme in your app's " +
                        "manifest is not set up correctly. You should have a " +
                        "com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity with the " +
                        "scheme: " + scheme);
                finish();
            }
        }

        private void showToast(String msg) {
            Toast error = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            error.show();
        }

        /**
         * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a local
         * store, rather than storing user name & password, and re-authenticating each
         * time (which is not to be done, ever).
         */
        private void loadAuth(AndroidAuthSession session) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
            String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, null);
            String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, null);
            if (key == null || secret == null || key.length() == 0 || secret.length() == 0) return;

            if (key.equals("oauth2:")) {
                // If the key is set to "oauth2:", then we can assume the token is for OAuth 2.
                session.setOAuth2AccessToken(secret);
            } else {
                // Still support using old OAuth 1 tokens.
                session.setAccessTokenPair(new AccessTokenPair(key, secret));
            }
        }

        /**
         * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a local
         * store, rather than storing user name & password, and re-authenticating each
         * time (which is not to be done, ever).
         */
        private void storeAuth(AndroidAuthSession session) {
            // Store the OAuth 2 access token, if there is one.
            String oauth2AccessToken = session.getOAuth2AccessToken();
            if (oauth2AccessToken != null) {
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
                Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, "oauth2:");
                edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, oauth2AccessToken);
                edit.commit();
                return;
            }
            // Store the OAuth 1 access token, if there is one.  This is only necessary if
            // you're still using OAuth 1.
            AccessTokenPair oauth1AccessToken = session.getAccessTokenPair();
            if (oauth1AccessToken != null) {
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
                Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, oauth1AccessToken.key);
                edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, oauth1AccessToken.secret);
                edit.commit();
                return;
            }
        }

        private void clearKeys() {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
            Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.clear();
            edit.commit();
        }

        private AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
            AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

            AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair);
            loadAuth(session);
            return session;
        }
    }
    `
```

Comment: In addition to the explanation in the answer to the question that this duplicates... it looks like you've got a typo in your activity class name `AuthActivitywith`.  You can remove the "with".